# 16-bit linking under linux

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, nasm, 16-bit

I'm using NASM Assembler under linux
when I use the command "nasm -f elf -l hello.lst  hello.asm"
it works fine
but when linking with gcc "gcc -o hello  hello.o"
it generates an error :

hello.asm:(.text+0x4): relocation truncated to fit: R_386_16 against `.data'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I learned that this is some problem with gcc and 16-bit

any solutions ?

Comment: Does your gcc installation have a 16-bit default runtime lib?

Comment: Looks like you're missing pieces of your cross-compiler toolchain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linux doesn't even have a 16-bit subsystem - even if you got gcc to link it, you still couldn't execute it! Why don't you just use `.bits 32`?

Comment: If you need to write 16-bit code for homework, I recommend doing so in DOSBox and using a DOS linker (NASM had regular DOS releases at some point, not sure if it still does). I'm not aware of *any* port of GCC / binutils to x86 16-bit, no matter the OS (closest thing is DJGPP, but that's still 32-bit and requires a DOS extender).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same situation a few years ago and again this year.

Two ways to deal with it are:

1. Write your own 16-bit friendly linker (you need to parse .rel.text section at least).
2. Use a base symbol (or symbols) to calculate the absolute addresses manually (the .rel sections are still created, but can be removed). However, this method is very error prone.

I always end up doing 2, but I should probably make time to write a linker (or patching GNU ld...).